# Execute a part of JS code after code above it

Tags: javascript, jquery

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/vJEFy/)

**HTML/CSS code is irrelevant to the problem, and so is most of JavaScript code**

In `line 51` of JavaScript, `console.log(mode);` I was expecting to see either `1` or `2` but instead I get `undefined`. My only guess is that the value was logged before the code inside `$pregame.on('click', 'button', function () { ...` did its job.

How can I make the code under `// ------------ game code ------------` run after the code above it? What options do I have?

---

**jQuery Code**

```
(function($) {
    var $pregame = $('div#pregame');
    var $notifier = $('div#notifier')
    var $game = $('div#game');
    var mode;


    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        $game.append($('div.frame').eq(0).clone());
    }

    var $frame = $game.find('div.frame');

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        var windowW = window.innerWidth, windowH = window.innerHeight;
        var gameLen = windowW < windowH * 0.9 ? windowW : windowH * .9;
        $game.css({
            'width':  gameLen + 'px',
            'height': gameLen + 'px'
        });
    }).trigger('resize');

    $pregame.on('click', 'button', function () {

        if ( $(this).data('mode') === 1 ) {
            mode = 1;
        } else {
            var $divs = $notifier.children('div');
            $divs.eq(0).text('Player 1').end().eq(3).text('Player 2');
            mode = 2;
        }

        $pregame.fadeOut(500, function () {
            $game.fadeIn(500);
            $notifier.css('display', 'table').animate({'opacity': 1}, 500);
        });

        $pregame.off('click');
    });

    // ------------ game code ------------

        var activeFrame = 4, gameArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            gameArray.push(['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-']);
        }
        console.log(mode); // <<----- THIS HERE <<---------
        if ( mode === 1 ) {
            $('body').on('click', 'div.frame', function() {
                var index = $frame.index(this);
                if ( index === activeFrame ) console.log('click on active Frame');
            });
        } else if ( mode === 2 ) {

        }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I am not sure but i think above code runs on page load and if you want to run above code you should create function and include code that you want to acces

Comment: I want the code under comment `// ------------ game code ------------` to run after code above it so I can get a `1` or `2` value of `mode`. Currently I get `undefined` in Fiddle

Comment: $pregame.on('click' this function is only called after click hence you may need to move code to click function or you can call click function before game i.e. $(element).trigger('click')

Comment: It *does* run after the code above it (appending divs, attaching listeners etc). It does not run after the click event of course. Do you want that? Then put it *inside* the handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it where `mode` isn't defined until you click the pregame button, it is not called by the time you evaluate mode at line `51`.

One solution would be to move the `});` on line `42` to line `60`.
This way, the gamecode section also will not be ran until you click.

Comment: I'll go with your solution. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

One Solution that just struck my mind is to use Callback functions. Wrap game code in a function like this:

```
function callMeLater() {
    var activeFrame = 4, gameArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        gameArray.push(['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-']);
    }
    console.log(mode); // <<----- THIS HERE <<---------
    if ( mode === 1 ) {
        $('body').on('click', 'div.frame', function() {
            var index = $frame.index(this);
            if ( index === activeFrame ) console.log('click on active Frame');
        });
    } else if ( mode === 2 ) {

    }
}
```

and call it from `.animate()`

```
$notifier.css('display', 'table').animate({'opacity': 1}, 500, callMeLater);
```

But this seems a bit weird to me. Any other choice that I have?